# Windows Phone 8 - Issue when decoding RSS XML special characters

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, windows-phone-8, rss

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that uses the following code to obtain the XML RSS data from a website:

```
public async Task GetArticles()
{
    string rssData = string.Empty;
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("http://MY_RSS_URL.xml"));
    var response = await new HttpClient().SendAsync(request);

    rssData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    rssData = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(rssData);
}
```

However, I still have special characters in my XML, such as ***& raquo;*** and ***& #8217;***, even after using **WebUtility.HtmlDecode**.

Is there another function I can take advantage of to convert these to **»** and **’**? Or perhaps there's a way that I can have them display properly in a **TextBlock**?

Comment: Have you tried [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)

Comment: I'll give it a shot. But I read that it's more advantageous to use WebUtility?

Comment: seems like there's space after `&`..Remove that space..That should work

Comment: `Regex.Replace(input,@"(?<=&)\s+(?=[^;]*;)","");`

Comment: @Anirudh thank you for your help, but I had to put the space there so that the special character would show. In my XML data, there's no space